# How to control cd-Rom 3 phase Sensored BLDC Motor with arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have one of these cd-rom bldc motors:
[image]

I would like to control it using a mcu. However, I am not sure how I would wire it up. I found [this post](http://elecnote.blogspot.se/2014/11/cd-rom-3-phase-sensored-bldc-motor.html) doing exactly this, however a 3-Phase BLDC motor bridge is required to drive it, which can be built using a few mosfets and transistors. But I am sure there is something like this already available but I couldn't find anything suitable for my application.

Are there any simple 3-phase bridge bldc motor bridges available and if there are how do I wire it to my cd-rom bldc motor?

Comment: This isn't really a fit here as it is somewhere between two broad and a sourcing question.  Obviously, appropriate driver chips exist as found in the product this came from, but may not be easy to work with.  A dual H bridge would do it (ignore the 4th channel).  To spin the motor unloaded for demonstration purposes you can actually use the ATmega outputs with perhaps some series resistors to limit current, and you may even be able to get it to run open loop.  Look to the RC hobby world if you want a low-cost reprogrammable driver for brushless motors of this size on up.

Comment: The smart thing to do is scope an existing CD motor drive circuit and extract the interface logic signals to duplicate and cut out the driver section. To get the same performance and learn how it is done correctly by creating a schematic from tracing the layout. Don't guess.